# Mysql Database Design of Nested Login (Another Login After Login)

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my application there are two users Manager and Team.
Here in it in first login i'm checking that user is manager or team member. I'm checking it through user_type.
So,

```
## User's table ##
----------
--> fieldnames

'user_id' 'username' 'email' 'password' 'user_type' (if 1 = user is manager , 0 = user is team member )
Row 1 -> '1' 'abc' 'abc@gmail.com' 'abc' '1' (user_type = 1 so Manager)
Row 1 -> '2' 'def' 'def@gmail.com' 'abc' '0' (user_type = 0 soTeam Member)


## Team's table ##
----------
--> fieldnames

'team_id' 'teamname' 'teamcode' 'user_id' 'user_type' 
Row 1 -> '1' 'TeamName1' 'AFE1(0' '1' '1' 
Row 2 -> '2' 'TeamName2' 'BCD@1(' '2' '1'
```

(So, TeamName1 is added by abc user and he is a Manager.

- Unique code (AFE1(0) is send to manager's email address and it's teamcode then manager will individually give to team members

  and now i'm stuck about team's uniqueness because Member can logout from  one team and login through another team's unique code and join another team)
- [SQLFiddle with the above data...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26331/1)

Note : Team Code is generated when a user is registered as a Manager.

- Unique code is send via email to manager . then manager will individually give that team code to the team member.
- and at the time of joining the team the team member will insert team code and then team member can join team.
- after joining the team manager can allocate task to the manager. Give feedback to the team member.
- And Team member can logout from one team and join another team.

Above process is after login as a team member or as a Manager.

So, My question is there is a Nested login (One login after another Login and task allocation process is based on "teamcode")

So, I'm confused about the database structure because teamcode is also unique and team_id is also unique ?

Comment: @ryan . i'm still now stuck in this question if you have any idea please tell me.

Comment: @RyanVincent  . Thank you for the reply...
Manager Can be a Team Member of Another Team means 1st manager can add 2nd manager as a team member by giving him team code so that time problem arise . yesterday my problem is solved by making complicated structure of mysql but as per my knowledge i find it very dirty so I want some perfect structure of database when this kind of work is repeated.

Comment: The 'standard' way of dealing with this situation is to have a 'many to many' relationship between users - teams and roles. How are you representing the relationships? Why not show us what you have? i.e. add the `roles` table and the other tables linking them together.

Comment: @RyanVincent. Thank you for valuable contribution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand manager can be part of team member of other team, and also team member is part of manager of other team.

so you can not store user type in user table. so you need 3 table

1) user :  store user info like name email ect..

2) team : store team info like 'team_id' 'teamname' 'teamcode'

3) association : associate user and team with there roll 
                  (associationId, user_id, team_id, rollType)

if you want to store different password for each association then add password in association table.

when manager add one team then make entry in team with teamcode as well as associate it using insert entry in association table user_id = manger's user id team id you just created rollType 1 (user_type = 1 so Manager).

when manager create one user as team member them insert it in user table if it's not user of you system and associate it with rolltype 2.

if that user is already in user table than just associate it no need to enter it in user table.

so when user login you can get the list of team with there roll using associate table.

Comment: ohk. great that's the solution what i need. association of user and team
Thank you so..much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a check query for each login process whether a team member is already exist in one of other teams tables. İf there is a record for him then do your restrictions.

Comment: Brother i will definately do this after completion of my database design just now i'm stuck in the database design and uniqueness of team module.